# How to convert char(or Byte) with hexadecimal data in it, to an integer(decimal value)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos, ios7

I have

```
char tem;
```

Its value is shown as blow:

```
Printing description of tem:
(char) tem = '\xd1'
```

which should equals to `209` in decimal.

My question is how can I implement this conversion programmatically? That is I want to get a NSInteger that equals 209 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there’s something I’m overlooking here, but given that both char and NSInteger are integral types, can’t you just do

```
char tem = '\xd1';
NSInteger i = tem;
```

? Or perhaps, to avoid surprises from sign extension,

```
NSInteger i = tem & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `char` variable actually *is* a 8-bit integer. You don't have to convert it to a `NSInteger` to get its decimal value. Just explicitly tell the compiler to interpret it as an unsigned 8-bit integer, `uint8_t`:

```
char theChar = '\xd1';
NSLog(@"decimal: %d", (uint8_t)theChar);    //prints 'decimal: 209'
```

To convert it to a `NSInteger`:

```
NSInteger decimal = (uint8_t)theChar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If yours char in ANSCII, do this:

```
char a = '3';//example char
int i = (int)(a - '0');
```